# How can I access the content from my Github Organization's wiki that disappeared?

Tags: git, github, recover, github-organizations

I am part of a Github Organization that has been using the [Wiki feature](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122125634/https://guides.github.com/features/wikis/) for documentation in a private repository for over a year. We had created many pages for internal use, but the wiki disappeared in the last week.

We use a free organization account and free personal accounts. When we go to our wiki (e.g., `https://github.com/<organization-name>/<repo-name>/wiki`), it now does not show up and instead shows a banner with `"Upgrade to GitHub Team or make this repository public to enable this feature."`:

[image: Free organization wiki disappeared]

There does not appear to be any reference to this in the [Github Changelog](https://github.blog/changelog/) or [Roadmap](https://github.com/github/roadmap). We did not change the parent repository from Public to Private (the repository and wiki have always been private).

How can I recover the content from the now-inaccessible wiki?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that while the wiki display is gone, the wiki content is still accessible from the repository.

The content can be recovered by cloning the wiki locally (see the [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages#cloning-wikis-to-your-computer)):

```
git clone https://github.com/<organization-name>/<repo-name>.wiki.git
```